# HTML doesn't recognize jpg file

Tags: php, html

I have this very simple program in PHP and HTML. I am using Microsoft SQL Server

```
<?PHP 
echo "A <br/>";
echo "End of PHP <br/>";

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
  <div id="Logo" ><img src="Images/Pic1.jpg" ></div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

The program doesn't recognize Pic1.jpg image and when run this php, the result is no image.

[image: Result of PHP program]

Thanks in advanced

Notice: I developed a small website to an organization one year ago and it is working live. Now they asked me to do some changes, but I couldn't do any thing because this problem is appeared when I work in localhost which I worked in before that.   Very strange, right?

Comment: So Pic1 is in localhost/[crossedoff]/Images/Pic1.jpg?

Comment: usually means the path is wrong.  What is the full path of the image on the server?

Comment: what is the location of your image file in relation to your html file? Right now it's looking for the image at:
Images/Pic1.jpg

Comment: Are you pointing the image to the right location?

Comment: If your crossed off folder name isn't `folder/Images`, then that's why. What webserver are you using, Mamp?

Comment: Try using an *absolute* path to the image, instead of a relative one.

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: the src has to match the web path of the image.  In this case it's looking for a folder called image that contains pic1.jpg starting where the executing file is located.  If it's in the root of your website, you may have better luck with ~/images/pic1.jpg as your path.

Comment: Sorry I don't know to answer every one comment.The path is correct. I am using SQL server. If I write the same HTML code in an HTML file, it works but within PHP not.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I added this line but the result became nothing, all the page empty

Answer (score 1):

```
 <img src="Images/Pic1.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="Photo"/>
```

It's xHTML not HTML so try this and check image path Images/Pic1.jpg

Comment: <img src="Images/Pic1.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="Photo"/>

Comment: Same thing. Also I put the jpg in the same php program folder, but nothing change

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/><title>test</title></head><body><p align="center">  <div id="Logo" ><img src="Images/Pic1.jpg" ></div></p>   </body></html>

Comment: Tested on my site with page source above works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If your path is good, you can also check `sharing and permission` of the file.
Public permission is usualy denied if it comes from the web

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use absolute path, or verify with your server's configuration (httpd.conf or nginx's virtuial.conf) what is set as a document root of your web server and then verify the Images directory seats in this path relative to the document root.